# Can I test if a regex is valid in C# without throwing exception

Tags: c#, regex

I allow users to enter a regular expression to match IP addresses, for doing an IP filtration in a related system. I would like to validate if the entered regular expressions are valid as a lot of userse will mess op, with good intentions though.

I can of course do a Regex.IsMatch() inside a try/catch and see if it blows up that way, but are there any smarter ways of doing it? Speed is not an issue as such, I just prefer to avoid throwing exceptions for no reason.

Comment: I have a method to test whether a RegEx is valid, but it just wraps the regex in a Try/Catch. I'm not sure if there's a better way to do this, but I couldn't find one.

Comment: do you mean blowing up on creating the actual Regex? new regex(str) ?

Comment: Allowing the users to enter a start and end value for each octet (or a similar solution) might be worth considering instead of regex.

Comment: You might also consider using CIDR (192.168.0.0/24) if your IP address regex is for ranges. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIDR

Answer (score 42, accepted):

As long as you catch very specific exceptions, just do the try/catch.

Exceptions are not evil if used correctly.

Comment: The question specifically asks if it can be done without handling an exception.

Comment: `Exceptions are not evil if used correctly` but they are expensive to throw as they include a dump of the stack trace inside of them. Exceptions should be used for actual errors (ideally) and not for testing inputs

Comment: `but they are expensive to throw` I just spent the day trying to convert MS `RegexParser.ScanRegex()` into something that will return just an `enum` representing the error.  I would bet that while exceptions may be memory expensive to throw, that there would be a significant performance cost to adding a bunch of checks. if I finish it I'll benchmark it.

Comment: I guess I'll eat my hat https://github.com/mwagnerEE/BenchmarkResults/blob/main/ToThrowOrNotToThrow-report-github.md

Answer (score 61):

I think exceptions are OK in this case.

Just make sure to shortcircuit and eliminate the exceptions you can:

```
private static bool IsValidRegex(string pattern)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(pattern)) return false;

    try
    {
        Regex.Match("", pattern);
    }
    catch (ArgumentException)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: I wonder will JIT compiler be smart or dumb enough to optimize away the whole try catch block because the return value of a pure function is not used?

Comment: Would `IsMatch()` be any faster/better than `Match()`, seeing that we don't actually want to perform a match? Just like testing for primality is infinitely (well, almost) faster than actually finding the factors.

Comment: `IsMatch()` [calls](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Text.RegularExpressions/src/System/Text/RegularExpressions/Regex.cs) `internal Match Run(bool quick, int prevlen, string input, int beginning, int length, int startat)` with `quick` set to `true` while `Match()` calls it with `quick` set to `false`. It is indeed a bit faster, about **1-5%** according to my simple tests.

Comment: How about just `new Regex(pattern)`?

Comment: Question specifically asks if it can be done without handling an exception.

Comment: Does `RegexParseException` need to be handled as well?

Comment: Never mind, `RegexParseException` is an `ArgumentException`.  Catching ArgumentException will handle both!

Answer (score 8):

Not without a lot of work. Regex parsing can be pretty involved, and there's nothing public in the Framework to validate an expression.

`System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexNode.ScanRegex()` looks to be the main function responsible for parsing an expression, but it's internal (and throws exceptions for any invalid syntax anyway). So you'd be required to reimplement the parse functionality - which would undoubtedly fail on edge cases or Framework updates.

I think just catching the ArgumentException is as good an idea as you're likely to have in this situation.

Comment: We have TryParse to deal with potentially malformed numbers.  We should have a TryRegex to do the same thing--return a failure rather than an exception.  Debugging user-entered regexes is annoying!

Comment: I think its actually `System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexParser.ScanRegex()` Source: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/regex/system/text/regularexpressions/RegexParser.cs

Answer (score 5):

I've ever been use below function and have no problem with that. It uses exception and timeout both, but it's functional.
Of course it works on .Net Framework >= 4.5.

```
    public static bool IsValidRegexPattern(string pattern, string testText = "", int maxSecondTimeOut = 20)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(pattern)) return false;
        Regex re = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.None, new TimeSpan(0, 0, maxSecondTimeOut));
        try { re.IsMatch(testText); }
        catch{ return false; } //ArgumentException or RegexMatchTimeoutException
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: plz change the timespan, it should be TimeSpan(0,0,maxSecondsTime...) instead of hardcoded "20"

Comment: I changed it now. Thank you so much my friend.

Answer (score 2):

A malformed regex isn't the worst of reasons for an exception.

Unless you resign to a *very* limited subset of regex syntax - and then write a regex (or a parser) for that - I think you have no other way of testing if it is valid but to try to build a state machine from it and make it match something.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on who the target is for this, I'd be very careful.  It's not hard to construct regexes that can backtrack on themselves and eat a lot of CPU and memory -- they can be an effective Denial of Service vector.

Comment: Is there no "stack overflow" protection in the .NET regex parsing library? Can you give me an example that might give me trouble?

Comment: Regex.IsMatch("bbbbbbbbbb", "(.*){50}a");

Comment: With .NET 4.5, you can add a timeout value to your Regex object

Answer (score 0):

In .NET, unless you write your own regular expression parser (which I would strongly advise against), you're almost certainly going to need to wrap the creation of the new Regex object with a try/catch.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution, that outputs an enum telling whether the pattern is
useable, and if yes, then return the compiled regex as an out parameter that
you can use directly in your calling code.
Regards.

```
namespace ProgrammingTools.Regex
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;    

    public enum eValidregex { No, Yes, YesButUseCompare }

    public class RegEx_Validate
    {
        public static eValidregex IsValidRX ( string pattern , out Regex RX )
        {
            RX = null; 

            if ( pattern.Length == 0 )
                return eValidregex.No;

            List<char> c1 = new List<char>
            {
                '\\' , '.' , '(' , ')' , '{' , '}' , '^' , '$' , '+' , '*' , '?' , '[' , ']', '|'
            };

            if ( c1.Count( e => pattern.Contains( e ) ) > 0 )
            {
                TimeSpan ts_timeout = new TimeSpan(days: 0,hours: 0,minutes: 0,seconds: 1,milliseconds: 0);

                try
                {
                    RX = new Regex( pattern , RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase , ts_timeout );
                    return eValidregex.Yes;
                }
                catch ( ArgumentNullException )
                {
                    return eValidregex.No;
                }
                catch ( ArgumentOutOfRangeException )
                {
                    return eValidregex.No;
                }
                catch ( ArgumentException )
                {
                    return eValidregex.No;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return eValidregex.YesButUseCompare;
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score -3):

By using following method you can check wether your reguler expression is valid or not. here testPattern is the pattern you have to check.

```
public static bool VerifyRegEx(string testPattern)
{
    bool isValid = true;
    if ((testPattern != null) && (testPattern.Trim().Length > 0))
    {
        try
        {
            Regex.Match("", testPattern);
        }
        catch (ArgumentException)
        {
            // BAD PATTERN: Syntax error
            isValid = false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //BAD PATTERN: Pattern is null or blank
        isValid = false;
    }
    return (isValid);
}
```

Comment: The title specifically says "without throwing exception"!

Comment: Trimming the pattern is also bad form since it might contain spaces for matching