# How to validate if a string is a regular expression?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

My application includes creating POCO classes at runtime using the CodeDOM. I am looking for a way to allow my end user to specify a limitation on the value of some properties he creates (e.g. if he adds a property Email than he would probably like to validate the content to an email address. It is obvious that the end user might have more custom restrictions).

My intention is to offer a `PropertyValidation` field where the end user can provide a regular expression which serve as a validator for the content of created instances of that property.

Is there any way I can make sure the string provided in the `PropertyValidation` field is an actual `Regex` before allowing it?

Comment: Use a `Try...Catch` block  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218680/can-i-test-if-a-regex-is-valid-in-c-sharp-without-throwing-exception

Comment: Do your end users know how to write regular expressions correctly? Keep in mind that a simple `hi` is a valid regex, but might not do what the end user wants. Also, some stuff (ie. mail addresses or even HTML input) cannot be validated through regexes easily. Additionally, badly written and frequently regular expressions can make an application slow.

Comment: What do you mean **valid**? This, `.`, is a valid Regex.

Comment: @TheSolution Yes, but this is not: `?`

Comment: @hangy: My end users are system administrators so yes they know how to right a regular expression

Comment: @TheSolution: I don't really care as long as they wrote it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to create a Regex object and catch any resulting errors:

```
try { Regex reg = new Regex(userDefinedValidation); } 
catch (ArgumentException) { /* not a regex */ }
```

Comment: You might want to catch `ArgumentException` as to avoid swallowing any unexpected errors.

Comment: Actually I just came up with this, was going to add it here and here you did :) Thank you!

Answer (score -3):

if the "Try-Catch way" is too general, then you should, for example, write a regex that parses correct regexes ;)