# How do I test if a replacement string needs to be a regular expression?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

I searched ... and searched...I don't mean [Can I test if a regex is valid](https://stackoverflow.com/q/218680/492), I want to test if a `replacement` string needs to be used in [Regex.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace(v=vs.110).aspx) or is a simple [String.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx) going to give me the same result, only faster.

ie. for a given string `replacement` do I **need** to use

```
Regex.Replace(input, replacement)
```

instead of

```
string.Replace(input, replacement)
```

This assumes (always a great idea) that string.Replace is faster than Regex.Replace.

edit: yes, a great idea. Not. [Regex.IsMatch vs string.Contains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2962670/regex-ismatch-vs-string-contains) for one.

Leaving this here as an example of premature optimization. As with most things in life - "It depends". I think that if you had hundreds or thousands of patterns then it may be worth sifting out the simple ones, depending on the likelihood of there being simple ones. For a manageable number of patterns, just do the Regex.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: "I want to test if a replacement string needs to be used in Regex.Replace or is a simple String.Replace going to give me the same result, only faster."  HOW?

Comment: Are you asking to figure this our dynamically? IE, I could give you any input string and you want to determine in code, ok choose `string.Replace` and then I give you another string and you determine use `Regex.Replace` because in this instance it's faster? Or are you asking which one is faster (period)?

Comment: Couldn't you set up some timers and test this pretty easily?

Comment: @Prescott fair point - edited the question to clarify

Comment: Would it be possible to see some sample values?

Comment: @CADbloke *HOW?* is not a question. It implies *write if for me*. Better, you write your test cases and ask here if you get a problem.

Comment: @Prescott Basically I'm looking for the presence if a wildcard-type replacement in the string (eg. `.*` `\d` `[a-z]`) - if there's not wildcard then it's just a simple string.Replace, if there's a wildcard then it is more involved.

Comment: Got it, thanks - I think you've got a reasonable answer then

Comment: @I4V "How" is a question but your point of it not being a genius-grade question may be valid. I never claimed to be a genius.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can safely assume that if `Regex.Escape(pattern) == pattern` then you can use a good old string replacement.

But this is micro-optimization... So do measure whether this actually is worth the additional complexity. I bet the regex engine can figure that out, but I may be wrong: either way, never make assumptions out of thin air in cases like that, but back them up with measures.