# How to check a specified regular expression in c#

Tags: c#

I am a beginner in Regular expressions and  I want to check if a string variable satisfy a specified expression like this :

```
R|numeric_value|^value0^^^value1|value2|value_or_null|date_value
```

**Note : The symbols (| and ^) are mandatory static characters and they are considered as Fields delimiters**

any one help please!

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you just want to check if a RegEx matches a pattern... have you searched how RegEx class works in C#? Give this a try https://stackoverflow.com/a/1775017/3563910

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use online services like http://regexstorm.net/tester but for your learning.
I recommend a T.D.D. approach with xUnit for example https://xunit.github.io/.

With something like that :

```
[Theory]
[InlineData("input_1", "pattern")]
[InlineData("input_2", "pattern")]
[InlineData("input_x", "pattern")]
public void ShouldMatch(string input, string pattern)
{
  try
  {
    var isMatch = Regex.IsMatch(input, pattern);
    Assert.True(isMatch);
  }
  catch (ArgumentException)
  {
    Assert.True(false);
  }
}
```

**EDIT :**

*Thank you for your response, But how can the pattern be ?*

1. Read the documentation [.Net Regular Expression Language - Quick Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference) .
2. Split your regex by logical OR/AND/NOR/NAND/etc operators .
3. Use the [Tdd cycle steps](https://www.whizlabs.com/blog/what-is-tdd-and-its-phases/) .
4. Solve the first expression .
5. Solve the second expression.
6. Solve both expressions with your logical OR/AND/NOR/NAND/etc operators between first and second expression.
7. Etc.

After this little exercise.
You will better understand how to build patterns by yourself.